# Include an image in PyInstaller executable file for other users

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I am compiling a .py script into a single .exe with PyInstaller, using the --onefile option. I am unable to include a .png file with the file.

I've included this code to locate the image within the .py script:

```
def resource_path(self, relative_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)

self.image(self.resource_path('Logo.png'), 10, 10, 50)
```

The last line is setting a header with an image in it; this code works fine when the absolute path was used as below:

```
self.image('C:/Users/Kieran/Desktop/SCIDTest/Logo.png', 10, 10, 50)
```

I then have this in the .spec file to include the image:

```
datas=[('C:\\Users\\Kieran\\Desktop\\SCIDTest\\Logo.png', 'data')]
```

Running the .exe, I get this error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Kieran\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI33002\\Logo.png'
```

Comment: The `--specpath` indicates that you want a `spec` file created, and saved in the indicated directory. If you want to use an edited `spec` file, just run `pyinstaller SCIDReporter.spec` from a command terminal in the same folder as the `spec` file. To add the `png` file, add a line like `datas = [('somefile.png', '.')],` under the `Analysis`.

Comment: Thanks, I believe that worked. Updated the post to focus more on the missing image issue now.

Comment: The line `datas=[('C:\\Users\\Kieran\\Desktop\\SCIDTest\\Logo.png', 'data')]` is telling `pyinstaller` to put the `png` file in the `data` directory, but your `resource_path` is not looking in a `data` directory. I think it will work if you just replace the datas line with `datas=[('C:\\Users\\Kieran\\Desktop\\SCIDTest\\Logo.png', '.')]`.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks much.